# How can i get value of selected date from datepicker in my controller?

Tags: grails, controller, datepicker, selectedvalue

I have two datepickers:

```
 <div class='input-group date datepicker1'>
       <input  data-format="dd/mm/yyyy" name="startDate" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" type='text' class="form-control" required/>
           <span class="input-group-addon">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
           </span>
 </div>

<div class='input-group date datepicker2'>
        <input  data-format="dd/mm/yyyy" name="endDate" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" type='text' class="form-control" required/>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
 </div>
```

I need to get values selected in both datepickers onchange (without submitting form) and pass those values to my controller so that i can substract their values and get difference between those two dates.

Please, help!

Answer (score 0):

Add ID tags to your HTML input snippets to reference them easier.

you snippet, updated

```
 <div class='input-group date datepicker1'>
   <input  id="inputOne" data-format="dd/mm/yyyy" name="startDate" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" type='text' class="form-control" required/>
       <span class="input-group-addon">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
       </span>
  </div>

  <div class='input-group date datepicker2'>
    <input  id="inputTwo" data-format="dd/mm/yyyy" name="endDate" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" type='text' class="form-control" required/>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
  </div>
```

Now since we are working with non-live Nodes, we can use JS to reference the inputs fast, then it's as easy as grabbing the values and watching for the change event. NOTE: Input fields have a specific event to listen for that isn't as buggy or hacky as onchange.

JS to get the values would look something like this:

```
var inptOne = document.querySelector('#inputOne');
var inptTwo = document.querySelector('#inputTwo');

function getValueOne() {
    var valOne = inptOne.value;
    return valOne
}

function getValueTwo() {
    var valTwo = inptTwo.value;
    return valTwo
}

    // NOTE THE USE OF "input" INSTEAD OF "onchange"
    // THIS WORKS NICELY WITH INPUT FIELDS
    document.body.addEventListener("input", getValueOne, false);
    document.body.addEventListener("input", getValueTwo, false);
```

The code above will give you access to further manipulate your input values.

Comment: well...thank you...this could be good...but..i need to remind you that i have to get these values in my controller...and i am new at this...

Comment: It may seem a little daunting, but you're already very close to getting where you want. Using the code I've written so far, you have access to the value of both input fields (via listener events). Taking it further, you could wrap the listeners in there own function, and immediately invoke it. Or you could wrap the entire snippet in an object, and return the events. Then invoke the object from within your controller. Do you need help writing the actual code?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using a g:link tag.

You can check http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Tags/link.html
for more info.

or you can just use plain g:textfield tag.

```
<g:textField name="startDate" required="" value="${yourDomainClassInstance?.startDate}"/>
```